# How to input all files within a directory with a certain ending? Python

Tags: python, file, function, input, directory

I have a folder called Test `'/Desktop/Test/'`

I have several files in the folder (eg. 1.fa,2.fa,3.fa,X.fa)

or `'/Desktop/Test/1.fa','/Desktop/Test/2.fa','/Desktop/Test/3.fa','/Desktop/Test/X.fa'`

**I'm trying to create an element in my function to open up every file in the directory** `'/Desktop/Test/'` that has an ending **.fa** without actually making a function with 20 or so variables (the only way I know how to do it)

Example:

```
def simple(input):

    #input would be the directory '/Desktop/Test/'
    #for each .fa in the directory (eg. 1.fa, 2.fa, 3.fa, X.fa) i need it to create a list of all the strings within each file 
    #query=open(input,'r').read().split('\n') is what I would use in my simple codes that only have one input
```

**How can one input all files within a directory with a certain ending (.fa) ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
import glob
import os
def simple(input)
    os.chdir(input)
    for file in glob.glob("*.fa"):
        with open(file, 'r+') as f:
            print f.readlines() #or do whatever
```